# CSS3 Transform Issues in IE10/IE11

Tags: debugging, svg, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I'm having trouble getting this svg to display correctly in IE10/IE11.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ryanbimmer/pen/cBptk) with my situation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simplified test:

```
<!doctype html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .rack-edit { transform: rotateY(140deg); }
   .figure { display: block; width: 500px; height: 300px; }
  </style>
 </head>

 <div class="rack-edit">    
  <figure class="back">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="444" height="294">
      <rect stroke="black" stroke-width="10" width="10" height="10" />
    </svg>
  </figure>
 </div>
```

Get that working the same in all three browsers, then go from there.